# How to Implement an LDAP Custom Login Page

Tags: authentication, custom, login

I have read various guides on how to configure FBA with LDAP Membership provider and i am able to successfully login by configuring the config files for Central Admin, STSA, and Web App by using a custom login page.

I have seen a number of issues with these methods, specifically around the people picker selections, display names of users, and the inability to search for groups.  I want to keep NT authentication but not have to use the membership providers, IE, I want to be able to replace the NT Challenge prompt with a form login prompt that creates a SharePoint authentication token and then redirects to the main site.

I don't mind doing this in a separate ASP.Net app if necessary, but I cannot seem to find any good examples on how to create a valid authentication token so that the user is not prompted to enter.

Is this even possible (Effectively SSO into SharePoint 2010)?

Answer (score 0):

Writing your own token issuer is a large, complicated task. If your goal is to have a login page instead of the default prompt, then configure IIS to use Basic Auth over SSL. This will retain the NT Authentication and the OOB People picker experience.

Comment: Do you have an example of how i would create a basic authentication ticket using Basic Auth?

Comment: That is just it -- you don't need to. Let IIS take care of Auth for you.

Comment: Well, it helped a bit...i have still been struggling with it.  Turns out IE will not let you use a username and password in the URL so passing the authentication details through the url is not an option...back to the drawing board :(